# find all data from dictionary collection value to another dictionary collection key

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have dictionary collection

`{key -> string, value -> class}`

and I have another dictionary collection

`{key -> string, value -> string}`

note : 2nd dictionary collection `{key -> string, value -> string}.Value` is 1st dictionary collection `{key -> string, value -> class}.Key`

So, I have To find All Data From 1st dictionary collection  according to 2nd collection value.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL or ASP.NET?  And why have you tagged 2 languages?  All that's going to do is get your vague question closed _faster_.

Comment: Have you tried looping through the 2nd dictionary and searching for the item in the first by each key?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Please write the shell of the classes and define the dictionaries in your question so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Just to clarify - you REALLY need to include the code that is relevant to this post. Without code, we can't help at all. Any answers would be guesses.

Answer (score 1):

```
      class MyTest
      {
          public int myValue { get; set; }
      }

 Main()
      {
        Dictionary<string, string> First = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        First.Add("dd", "test");
        First.Add("ss", "test");
        First.Add("tt", "test");
        First.Add("aa", "test");
        First.Add("mm", "test");

        Dictionary<string, MyTest> Second = new Dictionary<string, MyTest>();
        Second.Add("dd", new MyTest() { myValue = 123 });
        Second.Add("oo", new MyTest() { myValue = 123 });
        Second.Add("tt", new MyTest() { myValue = 123 });
        Second.Add("aa", new MyTest() { myValue = 123 });
        Second.Add("rr", new MyTest() { myValue = 123 });

        var Final1 = First.Where(S => Second.Any(T => S.Key.Equals(T.Key)));

        var Final2 = Second.Where(S => First.Any(T => S.Key.Equals(T.Key)));

        Console.WriteLine("\nFirst\n");
        foreach (var item in Final1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "-" + item.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nSecond\n");
        foreach (var item in Final2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "-" + item.Value.myValue);
        }
 }
```

Comment: please explain more detail in your answer

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question you want to lookup the first dictionary based on a second dictionaries value.

```
public class Test
{
    public string MyValue {get;set;}
}
Dictionary<string, Test> DictOne = new Dictionary<string, Test>();
Dictionary<string, string> DictTwo = new Dictionary<string, string>();

DictOne.Add("DictOneKeyOne", new Test() { MyValue = "DictOneValueOne" } );
DictTwo.Add("DictTwoKeyOne", "DictOneKeyOne");

Test ValueFromDictOne = DictOne.ContainsKey(DictTwo["DictTwoKeyOne"]) ? DictOne[DictTwo["DictTwoKeyOne"]] : null;
```